# Should we merge the tags [sample] and [sampling]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, tag-synonyms

The tags [sample](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sample) and [sampling](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sampling) appear to have identical usage. This is what their wiki and excerpts look like:

**Sample:**

> *Excerpt:* Any question relating to the use of samples used in media. Do not use this tag to identify a sample, use [identify-this-sample] instead.
>
> *Wiki:* A sample is a portion of a sound recording (from movies, different musical works, radio interviews etc.) used in a musical work.
>
> Sampling originated in the 40's, using methods such as tape loops to repeat drum beats, and exploded in the 70's with Hip-Hop DJs using 2 turntables and a mixer to infuse song snippets over a new beat.

**Sampling:**

> *Excerpt:* For use with questions pertaining to songs which contain samples of other songs in them. Do **not** use this tag when referring to bitrates or other digital-based questions (i.e. sampling rates used in SACD).
>
> *Wiki:* Sampling is the term used when pieces of songs are broken down into smaller chunks and inserted in other songs. Usually this includes either a beat or rhythm (i.e. Trick Daddy using the guitar riff from Crazy Train in his song "Let's Go"), or a vocal line (i.e. Run-DMC using the vocal line from Aerosmith's "Walk This Way" in their own cover version of the Aerosmith classic).
>
> Sampling is widely used in Hip-Hop, Rap and EDM, though also used to a lesser degree in many other genres.

---

Can we merge these tags, since they seem to have the same usage?

Currently, there are 7 questions tagged [sample](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sample) with none unanswered, and 5 questions tagged [sampling](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sampling) with 1 unanswered. There are no questions tagged both [sample](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sample) and [sampling](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sampling).

Based on this, I suggest that we mark [sampling](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sampling) to be a synonym of [sample](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sample). I personally find the excerpt and wiki of [sample](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sample) to be written more clearly, so this is another reason for my suggestion to keep [sample](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sample) as the master tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the questions tagged [sampling](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sampling) have been retagged to [sample](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sample). The [sampling](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sampling) tag has been burninated.